# How to make one facet default?

Tags: search

I want to set facet value default, when we search it will automatically checked 1st facet.

Answer (score 1):

You should define hook_search_api_solr_query_alter and something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_solr_query_alter().
 */
function MODULE_search_search_api_solr_query_alter(array &$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $call_args['params']['fq'][] = 'FACET_MACHINE_NAME:YOUR_VALUE';
}
```

I hope it helped you.

The other way to do this described here http://www.eilyin.name/note/how-set-value-facet-default-drupal-54

Comment: thank you for reply,can you please tell me where to make these changes, because I'm learning customization.

Comment: You can declare this function in your custom module.

Comment: last question, how to find 'FACET_MACHINE_NAME:YOUR_VALUE' ?

Comment: Try to filter you page via facets and take them from url. I would be something link this - http://www.yoursite.com/search?f[0]=field_brand:versace. "field_brand" is facet machine name and "versase" is facet value.

Comment: ok thanks got it, Now I have created one module name as test then added above function in it and enabled module, but it giving me " Notice: Undefined variable: call_args in include_once()" and its not working.

Comment: Very strange, please provide your piece of code

Comment: function test_search_search_api_solr_query_alter(array &$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $call_args['params']['fq'][] = 'is_book_bid:1104';
}

Comment: mhh, do you use module search_api and search_api_solr?

Comment: yh I'm using both the modules

Comment: It's very strange. I don't understand how this error is happens. Can you provide full text of the error? With function name and number of line in code?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to search_api_solr_query_alter() must be an array, object given, called in D:\MyWamp\www\SimMgrDev\includes\module.inc on line 1101 and defined in D:\MyWamp\www\SimMgrDev\sites\all\modules\search_api\search_api.module on line 1338

Comment: ignore previous message

Comment: I was debugging query value that why error came, its shows null value to me, and function is not working, any other changes i have do more?